# Spring MVC send all model classes as json string

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, reflection, toolbox

I'm a noob to Spring MVC and JSON. I have a class hierarchy (interface, classes, subclasses) that I want to send across to my view and then resurrect the objects in the view (perhaps some Json library, currently using FlexJson).

The idea behind this is I'm trying to generate a toolbox depending on the classes in my configuration hierarchy, allowing users to create a system by dragging and dropping (using jQuery?) the items (types from configuration hierarchy), setting various attributes (properties) on each of those items, and eventually saving and sending the configuration back to be persisted.

So far...I've only got as far as harvesting the (sub)types (of objects) from the package using [Reflections Library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) as thus:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections( new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setUrls( ClasspathHelper.forPackage( "com.obsm.myapp.model.configuration" ) )
            .setScanners( new SubTypesScanner(false) )
            .filterInputsBy( new FilterBuilder().includePackage( "com.obsm.myapp.model.configuration" ) ) );
    Set<Class<?>> types = reflections.getSubTypesOf( Object.class );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of googling and trying and failing, I have settled with the following fix. I have a `Util` class that gets me a json string if I pass it a `Class`. I'm now using [Jackson Library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to get json representation.

```
public class Util {

public static String toJsonString( Class<?> entity )
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "";
    try {
        String toolItemMode = "";
        List<Class<?>> interfaceList = Arrays.asList( entity.getInterfaces() );
        if ( interfaceList.contains( IConnectableObject.class ) )
        {
            toolItemMode = "both";
        }
        else if ( interfaceList.contains( IConnectionSource.class ) )
        {
            toolItemMode = "source";
        }
        else if ( interfaceList.contains( IConnectionSink.class ) )
        {
            toolItemMode = "sink";
        }

        json = mapper.writeValueAsString( entity.newInstance() );
        ObjectNode objectNode = ( ObjectNode ) mapper.readTree( json );
        objectNode.put( "mode", toolItemMode );
        json = objectNode.toString();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
}
```

And then in the controller method I do it this way...

```
.....
Reflections reflections = new Reflections( "com.obsm.myapp.model.configuration" );
    Set<Class<? extends IConfigurationEntity>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf( IConfigurationEntity.class );
    Map<String, String> toolBox = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for ( Class<? extends IConfigurationEntity> configItem : classes )
    {
        toolBox.put( configItem.getSimpleName(), Util.toJsonString( configItem ) );
    }
model.addAttribute( "toolBox", toolBox );
.....
```

If someone has any better idea, and I'm sure lot of you have, I'm keen to learn about them. Hope this help someone. :-)